# Update statement on Linked Server takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I'm facing with a strange situation. I have the following `update` statement which takes too long, almost 30 seconds comparing to almost instantly a month ago, to perform to a linked server in Azure:

```
UPDATE es
SET es.ADFLAG3=1
FROM MYLINKEDSERVER.IMPERIALDB.DBO.ESFIDOCUMENTTRADE es
JOIN #WMS_CVR_ORDERCONFIRMAT WMSC on es.gid=WMSC.FDOCUMENTGID
```

How can I optimize this? What could be wrong? Thanks

**EDIT**

The remote scan within execution plan is 100%...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps a month ago there was very little data and now there is a lot. Linked servers are usually a bad idea

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - there is the same amount of data and using a LS was the logic in the first place. How else to access a DB hosted in Azure if not creating a local instance and then a LS?

Comment: How many records are in `#WMS_CVR_ORDERCONFIRMAT`? How many in `ESFIDOCUMENTTRADE`? How often does `#WMS_CVR_ORDERCONFIRMAT` change? How often does this query need to be run? Is there any date changed indicator in `#WMS_CVR_ORDERCONFIRMAT`? Are you able to enable CDC on the on-premises SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have multiple rows matching from the second table.  If so, `exists` might help:

```
UPDATE es
    SET es.ADFLAG3 = 1
FROM MYLINKEDSERVER.IMPERIALDB.DBO.ESFIDOCUMENTTRADE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM #WMS_CVR_ORDERCONFIRMAT WMSC 
              WHERE es.gid = WMSC.FDOCUMENTGID
             );
```

And in either case, you want an index on `#WMS_CVR_ORDERCONFIRMAT(FDOCUMENTGID)`.

Comment: Now it takes more than 30 seconds after creating the index. Something else for sure is wrong. I cannot figure what.

Comment: Did you try the _exists_ syntax?